# CakePHP: auth another controller

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I have a problem with allow access for not logged user.

I tried to use in users_controller:

```
public function beforeFilter()  {
     parent::beforeFilter();
     $this->Auth->allow('add');
 }
```

I have access only to `app/view/users` but i need access to `app/view/tools`.

What i should to write to get access?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$this->Auth->allow();` allows a single action within the controller you put it in.
You cannot allow access to `app/view/tools`...
You can allow access to the `add` action in the `ToolsController` with:

`$this->Auth->allow('add');` inside the `ToolsController`'s `beforeFilter()` method.

Read [the online documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html) it is explained very well.